# Is there any good way do make a POST request in Flutter, to a JSON?

Tags: json, post, flutter, request, http-post

So I have a Flutter App that takes data from an api in a JSON and Displays in a listview.builder. I now want to make a POST request and change data in the JSON. If you know how to do this, please add a response to this :)

JSON:

```
[
{
    "id": 29,
    "description": "Berlinmurens Fall",
    "state": "started",
    "assigned_users": [
        {
            "username": "hugo",
            "fullname": "Hugo Johnsson"
        }
    ],
    "subtasks": []
},
{
    "id": 30,
    "description": "Kubakrisen + Konsekvenser",
    "state": "started",
    "assigned_users": [
        {
            "username": "studentone",
            "fullname": "Student One"
        }
    ],
    "subtasks": []
},
{
    "id": 31,
    "description": "Mutual Assured Destruction (MAD)",
    "state": "new",
    "assigned_users": [
        {
            "username": "hugo",
            "fullname": "Hugo Johnsson"
        },
        {
            "username": "studentone",
            "fullname": "Student One"
        },
        {
            "username": "studenttwo",
            "fullname": "Student Two"
        }
    ],
    "subtasks": [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "description": "Vad betyder MAD?"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "description": "Vad har MAD att göra med Kalla Kriget?"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "description": "Vem vann tillslut för att de fick kraften över MAD?"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "id": 32,
    "description": "Hur vann USA?",
    "state": "new",
    "assigned_users": [
        {
            "username": "hugo",
            "fullname": "Hugo Johnsson"
        },
        {
            "username": "studentone",
            "fullname": "Student One"
        }
    ],
    "subtasks": []
},
{
    "id": 33,
    "description": "Stilig Google Presentation",
    "state": "done",
    "assigned_users": [
        {
            "username": "hugo",
            "fullname": "Hugo Johnsson"
        },
        {
            "username": "studentone",
            "fullname": "Student One"
        },
        {
            "username": "studenttwo",
            "fullname": "Student Two"
        }
    ],
    "subtasks": []
},
{
    "id": 34,
    "description": "Vem var John F Kennedy?",
    "state": "done",
    "assigned_users": [
        {
            "username": "studentone",
            "fullname": "Student One"
        }
    ],
    "subtasks": []
}
]
```

I want to change "state". via a POST request. Can someone show me how to do that?

Should I do it like this?

```
_postreq() async {

var url ="--ADRESS--";

var response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers:{ "Accept": "application/json" } ,
    body: { "state": 1}, //key value
    encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8")
);

print("post");

return response;
}
```

JSON with individual task/29

```
GET /api/task/29/
HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
"id": 29,
"description": "Berlinmurens Fall",
"state": "started",
"assigned_users": [
    {
        "username": "hugo",
        "fullname": "Hugo Johnsson"
    }
],
"subtasks": []
}
```

AND THE UI

```
_postreq() async {

var url ="http://studieplaneraren.pythonanywhere.com/api/task/29/";

var response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers:{ "Accept": "application/json" } ,
    body: { "state": "done",}, //key value
    encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8")
);

print("post");

return response;
}
```

Backend Code

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
<meta name="description" content="Mouldifi - A fully responsive, HTML5 based admin theme">
<meta name="keywords" content="Responsive, HTML5, admin theme, business, professional, jQuery, web design, CSS3, sass">
<title>{{projekt.titel}}</title>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var url ="http://192.168.1.10/update.php";

//Metodo post
var response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers:{ "Accept": "application/json" } ,
    body: { "state": 1}, //key value
    encoding: Encoding.getByName("utf-8")
);
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192601/discussion-on-answer-by-victor-ortiz-is-there-any-good-way-do-make-a-post-reques). Please make sure to [edit] the answer to incorporate any relevant information from the discussion.